# aligning two elements per row in an align environment

Tags: equations, align

Is it possible to align the first and second equal signs respectively in each row (as in [image: sample equation])? I've been trying to find answers but not luck yet (I am a beginner). Thank you!

Here is the my current code for the equation:

```
\begin{align*}
\bigtriangleup{AEG}&=\ds\frac{1}{2}\times\overline{\rm{AE}}\times\overline{\rm{EG}}=\ds\frac{1}{2}\times\overline{\rm{EF}}\times\overline{\rm{AG}}\\
&=yx=f(\ds\frac{a^2+b^2}{a+b})\\
&=\ds\frac{ax^2}{b}=\ds\frac{ab}{a+b}(\ds\frac{a^2+b^2}{a+b})\\
&=\ds\frac{ax^2}{b}=\ds\frac{a^3 b+ab^3}{(a+b)^2}\\
&=x^2=\ds\frac{b}{a}(\ds\frac{a^3 b+ab^3}{(a+b)^2})\\
&=x^2=\ds\frac{a^2 b^2+b^4}{(a+b)^2}\\
&=x^2=\ds\frac{b^2(a^2+b^2)}{(a+b)^2}\\
&=x=\ds\frac{b\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}{a+b},
\end{align*}
```

Comment: welcome to TeX.SE! Please, extend your code fragment to complete, compilable small document. What is `\ds`?

Comment: Yes, please make it easy for us to copy&run your code. Thanks

Comment: How or where is `\ds` defined?

Comment: Off-topic: `\bigtriangleup` does *not* take an argument.  To cut down (a bit) on code clutter, you may want to replace `\bigtriangleup{AEG}` with `\bigtriangleup AEG`.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

[image]

With use of `alignat˙math environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{alignat}{3}
\bigtriangleup{AEG}
    & = \dfrac{1}{2}\times\overline{\rm{AE}}\times\overline{\rm{EG}}
        && = \frac{1}{2}\times\overline{\rm{EF}}\times\overline{\rm{AG}} \\
    & = yx
        && = f(\dfrac{a^2+b^2}{a+b})\\
    & = \dfrac{ax^2}{b}
        && = \dfrac{ab}{a+b}(\dfrac{a^2+b^2}{a+b})\\
    & = \dfrac{ax^2}{b}
        && = \dfrac{a^3 b+ab^3}{(a+b)^2}\\
    & = x^2
        && = \dfrac{b}{a}(\dfrac{a^3 b+ab^3}{(a+b)^2})\\
    & = x^2
        && = \dfrac{a^2 b^2+b^4}{(a+b)^2}\\
    & = x^2
        && = \dfrac{b^2(a^2+b^2)}{(a+b)^2}\\
    & = x
        && = \dfrac{b\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}{a+b},
\end{alignat}   
\end{document}
```

Comment: How do you get rid of the super ugly space in between the equations?

Comment: @jackson, with desired aligning of equation at `=˛` is this what you get. BTW, I would newer write equation on such a way ...

Answer (score 0):

To reduce the space between the two columns of equations, I propose to use `\mathrlap` from `mathtools`,at the cost that the second `=` sign in the first row won't be aligned. Another change: I think that fractional coefficients in equations look better with the medium-sized fractions from `nccmath` (~80 % of \displaystyle).

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}

    \begin{document}
        \begin{alignat}{2}
    \bigtriangleup{AEG}
        & = \mathrlap{\mfrac{1}{2}\times\overline{\rm{AE}}\times\overline{\rm{EG}}= \mfrac{1}{2}\times\overline{\rm{EF}}\times\overline{\rm{AG}}} \\
        & = yx
            && = f(\mfrac{a^2+b^2}{a+b})\\
        & = \frac{ax^2}{b}
            && = \frac{ab}{a+b}(\dfrac{a^2+b^2}{a+b})\\
        & = \frac{ax^2}{b}
            && = \frac{a^3 b+ab^3}{(a+b)^2}\\
        & = x^2
            && = \frac{b}{a}(\dfrac{a^3 b+ab^3}{(a+b)^2})\\
        & = x^2
            && = \frac{a^2 b^2+b^4}{(a+b)^2}\\
        & = x^2
            && = \frac{b^2(a^2+b^2)}{(a+b)^2}\\
        & = x
            && = \frac{b\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}{a+b},
    \end{alignat}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! However, I don't need the numbers on the right, is there a way to not include it? I haven't tried the code yet as I am not using my laptop currently.

Comment: @Yotaro: Yes, it's quite simple: use the `alignat*` environment in the place of `alignat`. In case  you need a single number, use the `equation` environment and nest in it the `alignedat`  environment.

Answer (score 0):

A few remarks before going for a solution.

1. `\ds` quite likely stands for `\displaystyle`. Forget it: display style is automatically chosen in `amsmath` displays and in inline math it makes for bad line spacing.
2. `\rm` has been deprecated for about 30 years. Also, if you make the letters upright after the second equals sign the same letters should be upright at the beginning.
3. `\bigtriangleup` doesn't take an argument: it's an operation symbol, so in your context you want to brace it (or make a personal command, see later).

Since you don't want to number lines and surely you don't want big gaps in the lines after the first, you can use a nested `alignedat`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\Triangle}{{\bigtriangleup}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\Triangle\mathrm{AEG}
  &=\frac{1}{2}\times\overline{\mathrm{AE}}\times\overline{\mathrm{EG}}
   =\frac{1}{2}\times\overline{\rm{EF}}\times\overline{\rm{AG}}\\
  &\begin{alignedat}{2}
  &=yx             &&=f\biggl(\frac{a^2+b^2}{a+b}\biggr)\\
  &=\frac{ax^2}{b} &&=\frac{ab}{a+b}\,\frac{a^2+b^2}{a+b}\\ % <-- no ()
  &=\frac{ax^2}{b} &&=\frac{a^3 b+ab^3}{(a+b)^2}\\
  &=x^2            &&=\frac{b}{a}\,\frac{a^3 b+ab^3}{(a+b)^2}\\ % <-- no ()
  &=x^2            &&=\frac{a^2 b^2+b^4}{(a+b)^2}\\
  &=x^2            &&=\frac{b^2(a^2+b^2)}{(a+b)^2}\\
  &=x              &&=\frac{b\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}{a+b},
  \end{alignedat}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Frankly, I see no reason for aligning the equals signs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\Triangle}{{\bigtriangleup}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\Triangle\mathrm{AEG}
  &=\frac{1}{2}\times\overline{\mathrm{AE}}\times\overline{\mathrm{EG}}
   =\frac{1}{2}\times\overline{\rm{EF}}\times\overline{\rm{AG}}\\
  &=yx             =f\biggl(\frac{a^2+b^2}{a+b}\biggr)\\
  &=\frac{ax^2}{b} =\frac{ab}{a+b}\,\frac{a^2+b^2}{a+b}\\ % <-- no ()
  &=\frac{ax^2}{b} =\frac{a^3 b+ab^3}{(a+b)^2}\\
  &=x^2            =\frac{b}{a}\,\frac{a^3 b+ab^3}{(a+b)^2}\\ % <-- no ()
  &=x^2            =\frac{a^2 b^2+b^4}{(a+b)^2}\\
  &=x^2            =\frac{b^2(a^2+b^2)}{(a+b)^2}\\
  &=x              =\frac{b\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}{a+b},
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, the last line is mathematically wrong.

Comment: Thank you so much for the comments. I understand that I have a lot to edit and improve. I would be grateful if you could point out why the last line is incorrect.

Comment: @Yotaro You have found that `x^2` is equal to something, but it's quite rare that `x^2` equals `x`.

Comment: Sorry i’m still confused. I simply took the square root of both sides. Should i have used an arrow (imply statement) statement instead?

Comment: @Yotaro Yes, but I'd not put this in the same display: finish at the `x^2` line and add some words such as “We have therefore proved that `\[x=...\]`“ with a separate display.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you!